# Power functions in an o-minimal expansion of an ordered field

Tags: abstract-algebra, model-theory

Let $\mathfrak{R}$ be a fixed o-minimal expansion of an ordered field $(R,<,+,\cdot,-,0,1)$ , A power function  is a definable endomorphism of the multiplicative group $(Pos(R) , \cdot ,1)$ .

- **Claim(1) :**  if $f:Pos(R)\rightarrow R$ is definable, not identically $0$, and $f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$ for all $x,y\in Pos(R)$ , then $f$ is a power function. that is $f(x)>0$ for all $x\in Pos(R)$
- **Claim(2) :** $(Pos(R) , \cdot ,1)$ is divisible, that is for any $x\in Pos(R)$ and for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ , there is some $y\in Pos(R)$ such that $y^n=x$
- **Claim (3) :** $x\rightarrow x^q$ where $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ is a power function. I have a problem with  raising to rational powers
- **some useful facts about o-minimal expansion of an ordered field**
- **fact(1) - the monotonicity theorem :** Every unary definable function is ultimately differentiable (with ultimately definable derivative), ultimately either constant or strictly monotone, and has a limit at $+\infty$ in $R \cup\{-\infty, +\infty\}$
- **fact(2)** : The mean value theorem and its usual consequences hold for definable functions.
- **fact(3)** : The groups $(R,+)$ and $(\operatorname{Pos}(R), \cdot)$ have no proper, nontrivial definable subgroups.
- **my attempt in showing that claim(3) follows from claim(2)**
  - assume that $(Pos(R) , \cdot ,1)$ is divisible consider the map $x\mapsto x^n$ . its kernel is a definable subgroup of $(Pos(R) , \cdot ,1)$ . by fact(3) it is injective and by divisibility it is surjective. thus we can define the nth root function, hence the rational exponents

any hints to **why the three claims hold** would be appreciated

Comment: hi Donnie Darko. can you be more clear about what your question(s) is/are?

Comment: I want to know why the three claims are true

Comment: for claim 1, first show that $f(x)\geqslant 0$ for all $x$ by noting that every element of $R$ is a square. then suppose $f(x)=0$ for some $x>0$. then $f(y)=f((y/x)x)=f(y/x)f(x)=0$ for all $y$, a contradiction

Comment: how to show that every element is a quare? for example in $\mathbb{Q}$ is an ordered field but $\sqrt(2)$ is not a square. i think that we need to use the o-minimality.
showing that every element is a square is a subcase of claim(2) i think.

Comment: for claim 2, do you know that every o-minimal field is real closed? that is the best way to see why claim 2 is true. finally, for claim 3, note that $(\mathrm{Pos}(R),\cdot)$ is divisible and torsion-free (divisible by claim 2, and torsion-free since $R$ is an ordered field). in any torsion-free divisible abelian group, elements have unique $q$-th roots for all rational numbers $q>0$. so, for a given rational $q=m/n$, the formula $\phi_q(x,y)\equiv (y^m=x^n)\wedge (x>0)\wedge (y>0)$ defines the graph of the $q$-th root function on $Pos(R)$.

Comment: try to replicate the proof that every positive real number is a square. in particular, fix $x>0$. consider the set $\{y\geqslant 0:y^2\leqslant x\}$. this is a definable set, and it is bounded above (why?), so by o-minimality it has a supremum (why?). show that this supremum is a square root of $x$

Comment: thank you sir, I'm working on your hints I'll come back in a moment

Comment: oh actually, I just saw you have Fact 3 at your disposal. this makes Claim 2 easier. indeed consider the map $x\mapsto x^n$. restricted to $Pos(R)$, this is a definable group endomorphism of $(Pos(R),\cdot)$. certainly it has non-trivial image, and its image is a definable subgroup of $Pos(R)$, so by Fact 3 its image is everything, giving the claim

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Atticus Stonestrom

- **Claim 1**

By theorem 2.3 in the article DEFINABLE SETS IN ORDERED STRUCTURES.I by ANAND PILLAY AND CHARLES STEINHORN, $R$ is a real closed field, in particular every positive element is a square. then $f(x)=f(y\cdot y)=(f(y))^2\geq 0$.

Assume for a contradiction that $f(x)=0$ for some $x>0$. Then for any $y\in Pos(R)$
$f(y)=f(y/x\cdot x)=f(y/x)f(x)=0$ which is absurd.

- **Claim 2** follows from **fact 3**

consider the map $x\mapsto x^n$. restricted to $Pos(R)$, this is a definable group endomorphism of $(Pos(R),\cdot)$. certainly it has non-trivial image, and its image is a definable subgroup of $(Pos(R),\cdot)$, since $(Pos(R),\cdot)$ have no proper, non trivial definable subgroup, its image is everything.

- **Claim 3**

We can use the same argument on the kernel of $x\mapsto x^n$ as in **Claim 2** to establish the infectivity of  that map. Or we can use the fact that every ordered group is torsion free.

Next, for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ define $x^{\frac{1}{n}}$ to be the unique element $y$ in $Pos(R)$ such that $y^n=x$. For $q=\frac{n}{m}\in\mathbb{Q}^+$ define $x^{\frac{n}{m}}$ to be $(x^{\frac{1}{m}})^n$ and for $q \in\mathbb{Q}^-$ define $x^q$ to be $(x^{-1})^{-q}$. It remains to verify that it is well defined and have the same propreties as in the case of $\mathbb{R}$. in particular it verifies : $(x\cdot y)^q=x^q\cdot y^q$.

Finally, the map $x\mapsto x^q$ **is definable:**

For $q\in\mathbb{Q}^+$, the map $x\mapsto x^{\frac{n}{m}}$ where $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$ is defined by the formula
$\phi_{n,m}(x,y)$ : $x^n=y^m \land 0<x \land 0<y$. And for $q<0$ $x^q=(x^{-1})^{-q}$, and since the map $x\mapsto x^{-1}$ is definable by the formula $\xi(x,y)$ ; $x\cdot y=1$. we can see that the map $x\mapsto x^q$ is definable as the composition of two definable maps.